# how to receive variables sent by transitionToRoute

Tags: ember.js

I read at

http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/

the following code:

I have a search box and want to send the value of the search box to the SearchController.

```
 App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({   // the initial
 value of the `search` property   search: '',

   actions: {
     query: function() {
       // the current value of the text field
       var query = this.get('search');
       this.transitionToRoute('search', { query: query });
     }   } });
```

How can i get the query parameter in the SearchController and then show it in search.hbs?

I am working with ember- cli.

The router is

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: NENV.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('search');
});

export default Router;
```

I set up a route under routes/search.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function (params) {
        console.debug("hi");
        return params;
    },
   setupController: function(controller,model) {
    var query = model.query;
     console.debug("query is");
     console.debug(query);
  }
});
```

When debugging i get an error:

> ember  More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments

Thanks,
David

Comment: Have you added a SearchRoute? What does your app Router look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your search route to be dynamic, so if you change your route definition to something like this

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('search', {path: '/search/:query});
})
```

This should work as you are expecting. Let me know if anything.

Cheers!